# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, exception

I'm writing a multi-threaded applicaiton in C#, VS2008. I used this code to change an element which was created using another thread:

```
          m_OwnerPump.Dispatcher.Invoke(
              System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
              new Action(
              delegate()
              {
                  m_OwnerPump.Name = textBoxPumpName.Text;
                  m_OwnerPump.Numbers = numbers.ToArray<string>();
                  //m_OwnerPump.City = tempInfo.City;
                  m_OwnerPump.EnergyConsumed = power;
              }));
```

It used to work peacefully but I don't know why  this exception is thrown all of a sudden!

Comment: `m_OwnerPump` appears to be a control, it simply should not have been 'created using another thread`.

Comment: It is a control but another thread in the code has created this.
When I don't use the Invoke method, I get this exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: Why another thread? That shouldn't have been the case.

Comment: While the main thread is loading the main window of the application, another thread is used to create Pump Controls in the window. I've done it in case to prevent program smoothness and waiting cursor for the user because the application is getting pump information from the server and it gets a little time, so it can be boring for the user.

Comment: @MOLi, **all** controls should be created on the main thread. Worker threads should only perform tasks not related to the UI. You will *never* be able to display a control created in a worker thread on the main window.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I'm displaying it with no problems!

Comment: When you create the secondary threads do you set their apartment state to STA? The main UI thread is STA.....when you create another thread and intend to do UI on it, (and it has it's own message pump), then you must make it an STA thead.  thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); ....  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suchit_84/creating-wpf-windows-on-dedicated-threads/   .....  http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/   .... don't mix controls/visual trees created in one thread with controls/visual trees created in another thread.

Comment: For reference only (for people that come across this question looking for ideas)....if you need to compose a control on a different thread...within a Visual Tree on a different thread, then HostVisual can be used. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just played around with the code, to finally found the problem. I don't know what's the exact reason, but it's now working.

The problem was with asking for another control's property inside the invoker, so I put the property value in a string and used it in the invoker and the final code piece is:

```
            string pname = textBoxPumpName.Text;
            m_OwnerPump.Dispatcher.Invoke(
              System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
              new Action(
              delegate()
              {
                  m_OwnerPump.Name = pname;
                  m_OwnerPump.Numbers = numbers.ToArray<string>();
                  m_OwnerPump.EnergyConsumed = power;
              }));
```

Comment: Was tempInfo.City (the one you commented out) created on your "main" UI thread?

Comment: Is textBoxPumpName was created on the same thread as on which m_OwnerPump was created?

Comment: So, that's why you are getting this exception since you are trying to access its property in other thread. Fair enough.